# Resolving an overloaded function call with a DWORD

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Using Microsoft C++ 2017, 64-bit build, the following line of code generates a compile error with ambiguous call to overloaded function:

```
print(pmc.PageFaultCount);
```

I have the following print functions defined, in the hope of unambiguously covering all integer types in common use:

```
void print(int32_t n);
void print(int64_t n);
void print(uint32_t n);
void print(uint64_t n);
```

`pmc.PageFaultCount` is declared as `DWORD`, which is documented as an unsigned 32-bit integer. I expected that to select the `uint32_t` overload.

How is this ambiguous?

More to the point, if the above set of overloads does not suffice to print any integer, what set of overloads would suffice?

Comment: An unsigned 32-bit integer value can implicitly be converted to an unsigned 64 bit value. That makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- not if there's an exact match, which in this case could be `uint32_t`.

Comment: Did the compiler tell you what the conflicting overloads are? Show the **exact** message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DWORD` is an alias for `unsigned long` while `uint32_t` is alias for `unsigned int`. So you need yet another set of overloads taking `long` and `unsigned long` (and probably for `unsigned long long` `long long`, `unsigned short`, `short`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, normal `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `std::byte` and enumerator types).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, so there is a `print` function for any integral type. These overloads should probably use "raw" type names rather than aliases though (that is take `unsigned int` instead of `uint32_t` for example).

Comment: On Windows using the standard WIN32 API, the type `DWORD` is an alias for a ***32-bit*** unsigned integer. Which matches `uint32_t` perfectly, and `uint64_t` through implicit conversion. Type-aliases doesn't matter in overload resolution. A 32-bit unsigned integer type is a 32-bit unsigned integer type, no matter what it's named.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is defined as `typedef unsigned long DWORD;` in `minwindef.h` in the latest SDK so it does not match `uint32_t` perfectly. Note that `long` is 32 bit (even on 64-bit builds).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude long to int is an *integral conversion*. Conversion from long to long long is also an *integral conversion*. Those conversions all have conversion rank and cannot be distinguished by overload resolution.

Comment: @Oliv That's kind of what I'm saying. Because conversion from a small integer type to a larger integer type, overloaded functions can be ambiguous.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But the sizes of the respective integral types is not significant here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `int`, `long`, `long long`, and their unsigned versions are always different types, even if they have the same number of bits. E.g. `is_same_v<int, long>` is always `false`.

Knowing this, `DWORD` happens to be defined as `unsigned long` on 64bit Windows, while `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` are defined as `unsigned int` and `unsigned long long` respectively. So, there is no perfect match for `DWORD` among your overloads. But, as `unsigned long` a.k.a `DWORD` can be implicitly converted to all of those types, you get an ambiguous call.

Note: on a platform where `long` and `unsigned long` are 64bit types, you will get the same ambiguity, just with `long long` and `unsigned long long` respectively.

To solve your issue, you need to add the missing overloads of `long` and `unsigned long` to really cover all integral types so that there is a perfect match for all of them.

You may want to rewrite your function signatures to from the `(u)intXX_t` aliases to `int`, `long`, `long long` and their unsigned variants to make it more obvious that everything is covered. You may also want an overload for `short` and `unsigned short`.